# Wait function for element to be visible doesn't work javascript

Tags: javascript, wait

I have this function to set a pause of some seconds waiting while elements be visible.

```
function waitElement(ms)
{
var d = new Date();
var d2 = null;
do { d2 = new Date(); }
while(d2-d < ms);
};
```

Then I want to apply a loop over all items with same class waiting 3 seconds before the next command in order to wait the loading of the element,
but doesn't seem wot work.

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("Class1");  

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { 
    items[i].click();
    waitElement(3000)
    document.getElementById("ID_1").click();
    waitElement(3000)
    document.getElementById("ID_2").click();
    waitElement(1000)
};
```

but if I run this code it works

```
waitElement(3000);
items[0].click();
```

But if I add one more command doen't work:

```
waitElement(3000);
items[0].click();   // This command it works
waitElement(3000);
document.getElementById("date_time_portlet_204").click(); // This command is not executed

Error: Empty string passed to getElementById() //This error is obtained
```

Someone could help me to fix my issue please.

Comment: Are you using `waitElement(3000);` for a delay in your code?

Comment: @window.document Yes. I'm trying to set a pause to wait the next element to be visible like I show in the code I posted.

Comment: Just use [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) then also can you provide a snippet of your code?